# How can I decompose a Gradle build into multiple files?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm writing a Gradle plugin which contains a collection of multiple chunks of independent configuration which will be applied to any project applying the plugin.

I want to keep the fragments very separate to discourage other people from adding unrelated logic to an existing place, and to improve visibility of what the plugin is actually configuring.

So I thought I could do this:

```
class CommonChecksPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  @Override
  void apply(Project project) {
    project.apply plugin: 'base'

    def resolveFile = { filename ->
      new URL(buildscript.sourceURI.toURL(), filename)
    }

    project.apply from: resolveFile('configuration1.gradle')
    project.apply from: resolveFile('configuration2.gradle')
  }
}
```

Example `configurationN.gradle`:

```
task 'checkSomething', type: CheckSomething
```

Problem is, this Java class `CheckSomething` cannot be resolved.

Is there a sensible way to do this other than just giving up and moving all the sub-scripts in as full Groovy classes? I'm reluctant to move them to classes, because I want to apply the same checks to the plugin project itself, and it seems difficult to apply them if they require compilation.

Comment: Does it work when you specify fully-qualified class name in *configurationN.gradle*?

Comment: @denis.zhdanov apparently not. :(  I tried adding some code into configurationN.gradle to print out the classpath, and it only contained a temporary directory with just the script class in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The applied script has a different classloader to the plugin, it doesn't inherit the buildscript classloader so therefore the task isn't on the classpath. You can do the following:

```
project.ext.CheckSomething = CheckSomething
project.apply from: resolveFile('configuration1.gradle')
```

See https://discuss.gradle.org/t/buildscript-configurations-classpath-not-available-in-apply-from-scripts/1391

Comment: Okay, so this does work around it for one case, where another project has imported my plugin. But it doesn't work around it for the other case, where my plugin is trying to apply the stuff itself, because the plugin can't access the class from its own build file.